# Swap 2nd thermostat for *off* swtich downstream of 1st thermostat

Tags: wiring, switch, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have two thermostats running two different fans wired up like this:

[image]

I'd like to replace the 2nd thermostat (on the right, in box #2) with a switch. I have done this and have the ability to turn Fan #2 always on, regardless of thermostat #1. I'd like the opposite, and am not sure how to wire it.

Desired operation:

- Thermostat #1 controls both Fan #1 and Fan #2 at the same time.
- If new switch (replacing Thermostat #2) is off, Fan #2 does not run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace A with B.  In Box#1 disconnect the live wire to the switch for Fan#2, from the 120V source and connect it to the Fan#1 terminal.

*If these "high voltage" thermostats are actually carrying the load current, not using a relay, make sure Thermostat 1 can handle the current for both fans.*. Look at the labelling or documentation for the thermostat and for the fans to figure that out.

[image]